# how to display three images consecutively in a stage using libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm creating a splash screen in libgdx so i need to display three images consecutively to my stage

```
private float time;
private int counter=10;

public void update(float delta) {

    stage.act(delta);
    counter-=Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime();
    counter-=delta;
    if (counter==3)
    {
        stage.addActor(oneImg);
    }
    else if(counter==2)
    {
        stage.addActor(twoImg);
    }
    else if(counter==1)
    {
        stage.addActor(splashImg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `stage.draw()`?

Comment: of course i did but there is something that goes wrong E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 23278
                  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: your code is not enough to find out your exception and please post complete logcat error

Comment: you can find there erroe here :https://pastebin.com/MgryXray

Comment: you can find my code at this link https://pastebin.com/yeCVMscB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've `NullPointerException` because your `splashImg` is null when you're setting origin of `oneImg` `Image`.

```
Texture one = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/one.png"));
oneImg = new Image(one);
oneImg.setOrigin(splashImg.getWidth() / 2, splashImg.getHeight() / 2);  // splashImag is null here
```

And one more thing `show()` called once in `Screen` Lifecycle and counter having 10 value at that time so your `Actor` oneImg, twoImg and splashImg will not added to stage. In `Screen` Lifecycle `render()` called after `show()` .

```
if (counter==3){
    stage.addActor(oneImg);
}
else if(counter==2){
    stage.addActor(twoImg);
}
else if(counter==1){
    stage.addActor(splashImg);
}
```